# Style Sheet Loading Problem

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, css, xhtml

Using C#

In my webpage style sheet is not loading, i am using Google Chrome Browser

Code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Data Entry</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="G:/style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
</head>
</html>
```

The above code is not loading the style.css file.

How to solve this issue.

Comment: Is the path correct? Relative to the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HREF is incorrect:

```
href="G:/style.css"
```

You need to either use a relative path:

```
href="../style.css"
```

Or if you must use a [file URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), use the correct one - this will mean only people with the correct browser/operating system and with `G` drive can see the stylesheet:

```
href="file:///g:/style.css"
```

Comment: Second one is not working(file:///g|/style.css), my stylesheet is located in G Drive, how to load the style sheet?

Comment: See my answer: href="file:///g:/style.css"

Comment: @Gopal - follow the link I posted about [`fileURI`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) to see what you could use.

Answer (score 0):

if it has to be on the file system:

`href="file:///g:/style.css"`

If your stylesheet is in the same folder as Default.aspx, use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```

In this case, the leading slash '/' is important because it points to the root of the domain, so if you page url is `http://localhost:8000/folder/anotherfolder/page.aspx`, then the `href="/style.css"` will still point to `http://localhost:8000/style.css`, not `http://localhost:8000/folder/anotherfolder/style.css`. This means that all of your pages will point to the same stylesheet in the same place.

If your stylesheet is in a sub folder of the application root such as css/, use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```

If it really is in G:/, copy it to the root of your application and use the first example above.